# A variável INTERNAL_IPS controla a variável DEBUG do Django?

Tags: django

Minha aplicação Django deve ser executada dois ambientes: um de desenvolvimento e outro de produção.

Quando executo no ambiente de desenvolvimento, acesso a aplicação pelo `127.0.0.1` e quando acesso produção, uso o meu domínio `www` normalmente.

No código da aplicação, tenho a necessidade de saber em qual ambiente estou e para isso uso a variável `DEBUG` do arquivo `settings.py`. Sei que posso fazer uma checagem pelos hostnames dos ambientes:

```
DEBUG = (socket.gethostname() == 'ambiente_dev')
```

Entretanto, vi que na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#internal-ips) existe uma configuração chamada `INTERNAL_IPS`. Se eu colocar o IP do ambiente de desenvolvimento nesta tupla, dessa forma:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = (
    '127.0.0.1',
)
```

A variável `DEBUG` ficará automaticamente com o valor `True` quando eu executar a aplicação no ambiente de desenvolvimento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente **NÃO**, exatamente no [proprio link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#internal-ips) que você postou ele diz:

> Allow the debug() context processor to add some variables to the template context.

E se você notar o tal `debug()` descrito também é um link, que leva para a página da documentação que explica que é exatamente ele:

> If this processor is enabled, every RequestContext will contain these two variables – but only if your DEBUG setting is set to True and the request’s IP address (request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']) is in the INTERNAL_IPS setting:
>
> - debug – True. You can use this in templates to test whether you’re in DEBUG mode.
> - sql_queries – A list of {'sql': ..., 'time': ...} dictionaries, representing every SQL query that has happened so far during the request and how long it took. The list is in order by database alias and then by query. It’s lazily generated on access.

Traduzindo, se esse processador estiver ativado, todo `RequestContext` conterá essas duas variáveis (`debug` e `sql_queries`), mas isto será **apenas** se a sua configuração `DEBUG` estiver definida como `True` e o endereço IP da solicitado (`request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`) estiver em `INTERNAL_IPS`.

Então ambos são complementares, mas não influenciam no comportamento um do outro e o contexto `debug()` apesar de presente precisará de ambas configurações.